# lista enlazada de datos dinamicos con templante

Tags: c++, lista, template

Hace poco me surgió una duda: tengo una plantilla de una estructura, y inicialmente es de un tipo, esta estructura es una lista enlazada, y quiero hace referencia a un nodo de otro tipo, quisiera escuchar alternativas, lo que inicialmente se me ha ocurrido es hacer lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>


template<class T>
struct nameStruct
{
    int index;
    std::string option;
    void (*myFunction)(T);
    nameStruct* next;
    nameStruct* pre;
};

int main()
{


    nameStruct<int> casa;
    casa.myFunction = mio;

    casa.next = new nameStruct<int>;

    return 0 ;
}
```

La idea seria poder tener una lista donde pueda hacer

```
casa.next = new nameStruct<long>; //<-Notese el long
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda, si es posible tambien me gustaria conocer sus alternativas para el problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con crear una herencia común para las diferentes especializaciones de la plantilla:

```
struct NodeBase
{
  virtual ~NodeBase() = default;

  NodeBase* next;
  NodeBase* pre;
};

template<class T>
struct Node : public NodeBase
{
  T value;
};
```

Ahora puedes enlazar nodos diferentes sin problemas:

```
NodeBase * node = new Node<int>;
node->next = new Node<long>;
```

Eso si, nota que un nodo no es una lista (o no debería serlo). Los nodos deberían quedar ocultos tras una capa (clase Lista):

```
class NodeList
{
public:

    ~NodeList()
    {
      // Se eliminan todos los objetos
      NodeBase* node = first;
      while( node != nullptr )
      {
         NodeBase * temp = node->next;
         delete node; 
         node = temp;
      }
    }

    void AddNode(NodeBase* node)
    {
      // Añadir el nodo al final de la lista
    }

    // ...

private:

    NodeBase* first = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Implementado tu solución me he topado con un problema, se me ha hecho imposible acceder a los valores. Eje: casa.next = new Node<long>;
    std::cout << casa.next->value;

Comment: @CoKeFish publica otra pregunta con el problema. No tiene sentido hacer una mega respuesta que solucione decenas de problemas porque entonces no le servirá a nadie